# Why direct reference materialized view is not recommended in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, materialized-views

Quoted from Oracle online document

> Unlike indexes, materialized views can be accessed directly using a SELECT statement. However, it is recommended that you try to avoid writing SQL statements that directly reference the materialized view, because then it is difficult to change them without affecting the application. Instead, let query rewrite transparently rewrite your query to use the materialized view.

I am not quite understand what exact meaning of `direct reference materialized view` in the context, it sounds like `SELECT` statement is OK but it is not recommended to join materialized view with order table/views by foreign key or even the `select` is not recommended at all? Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is suggesting that where you are using materialized views to pre-aggregate or pre-compute results, it is better to let query rewrite work rather than directly referencing the materialized view in a query.  If you are using materialized views to replicate data from a remote database, then query rewrite wouldn't come in to play and you would have to reference the materialized view directly.

Assuming that you are using materialized views to pre-aggregate results, let's work through a quick example.  Say that you have a simple data warehouse where you want to get the total sales for every product for the month.  Using the tables directly, you might have something like

```
SELECT p.product_name, 
       trunc( s.sales_date, 'MM' ) sales_month, 
       sum( s.sales_amt ) total_sales
  FROM sales_fact s
       JOIN product_dim p
         ON( s.product_id = p.product_id )
 GROUP BY p.product_name, trunc( s.sales_date, 'MM' )
```

If you want to optimize that, there are multiple materialized views that you could create and then rely on query rewrite to use those materialized views rather than hitting the tables directly.  For example, you might create a materialized view that aggregates the sales for each product for each day

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW sales_by_product_by_day
  ...
  ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS
    SELECT p.product_name, 
           trunc( s.sales_date ) sales_day, 
           sum( s.sales_amt ) total_sales
      FROM sales_fact s
           JOIN product_dim p
             ON( s.product_id = p.product_id )
     GROUP BY p.product_name, trunc( s.sales_date )
```

You could, of course, then go back and rewrite your query to use the `sales_by_product_by_day` materialized view, i.e.

```
SELECT product_name,
       trunc( sales_day, 'MM' ) sales_month,
       sum( total_sales ) total_sales
  FROM sales_by_product_by_day
 GROUP BY product_name, trunc( sales_day, 'MM' )
```

It would generally be better, however, to leave the query as it was (referencing the `sales_fact` and `product_dim` views) and to allow query rewrite to optimize the query by using the `sales_by_product_by_day` materialized view.  From a performance perspective, it doesn't matter whether you reference the materialized view directly or whether Oracle uses query rewrite to use the materialized view when you query the base tables.

By writing queries against base tables, however, you make it much easier for developers and DBAs in the future to tweak the set of materialized views that are available to optimize the full set of queries that people are running without having to constantly rewrite the queries.  For example, it might turn out that you wanted your materialized view to aggregate by product by store by month.  That materialized view would be a bit less efficient for this particular query but perhaps that would be more efficient for a number of other queries.  You could, of course, maintain both materialized views if you wanted to (incurring the overhead of maintaining many materialized views).  But, just as with indexes, you're often better off with a smaller set of indexes that work reasonably well for most queries rather than a large number of indexes that are ideal for each query.

In most data warehouse environments, the set of queries that people run will evolve over time so the set of materialized views that you want to use will also evolve over time.  If your queries go against the base tables, you can add and modify materialized views and use query rewrite to let the optimizer pick those up and to choose the best materialized view to rewrite against.  If your queries reference a particular materialized view, however, then Oracle can't rewrite against a different materialized view when one becomes available and changing the set of available materialized views in the future means manually rewriting a lot of queries.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I am using the materialized view in a j2ee application via JPA. so the view result is considered as an entity, I guess then the query rewrite is not an option as the entity must be designated with a solid table name, thus will not accept dynamic arrangement at run time. Then at this situation there is no way to avoid `SELECT * from MATERIALIZED_VIEW_ABC....` to refer query results from the view

Comment: @Dreamer - If you're using materialized views to preaggregate data rather than replicating data from a remote system, you wouldn't reference the materialized view as an entity in your application.  Your application would refer only to the base tables.  Oracle would then rewrite queries against the base tables to use the most appropriate materialized view.

Comment: I see so it is like to avoid to specify the materialized view (as an entity) in the application but better use same query to join base table. Oracle will rewrite the query if this feature(query rewrite) is activated when create the view. This will gain better performance.

Comment: @Dreamer - Correct.  If you're using materialized views to pre-aggregate data, you would ideally treat them very much like indexes.  You wouldn't generally want to add hard-coded hints to your queries to force particular indexes to be used, you'd generally rather let the optimizer figure out which index(es) are most efficient for a particular query since that may change over time as data volumes change and the set of available indexes change.